# Webstorm add breakpoint to a lib

Tags: node.js, debugging, webstorm

I've been struggling to make `Webstorm` hit breakpoints that I set within a npm package i.e. `node_modules`.

I can step into a lib code but the initial breakpoint should be set on your code. I wonder if there is a way to hit breakpoints within third party libraries.

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Stepping` -- there is `Do not step into library scripts` -- see if disabling that option will do any better. Other than that I may only recommend removing such package from being a Library so that such code will be treated as your ordinary project code.

Comment: Thanks @LazyOne. But I knew about that option thus I have already disable it. However, that is merely when you want to step into a lib code but after hitting a breakpoint in your code. It doesn't let you hit the breakpoint in a lib code. How Can I remove a package from being a Library?

Comment: Look at JavaScript Libraries in Settings/Preferences